# IntelliJ IDEA unable to find android sdk

Tags: android, macos, intellij-idea, libgdx

I'm trying to import a libGDX project into IntelliJ running OSX 10.9. When creating my own project it's not an issue specifying the path to the android sdk in the gdx-setup, but when importing one I keep getting the issue:

```
SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

[image: Screenshot]

I haven't found anything resembling a local.properties file and wouldn't know how to create one, so I set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable with the path to my android sdk, adding this to my .bash_profile: `export ANDROID_HOME=/Applications/android-sdk`
Additionally I added `$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools` to my PATH as well, which seems somewhat overkill, but unfortunately the [PATH isn't recursive](https://superuser.com/questions/345294/recursively-add-directory-to-path-variable).

IntelliJ isn't getting any of this however, I'm guessing adding it to my .bash_profile isn't the right way of doing it?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So thanks to the friendly people in the libGDX IRC it turned out to be relatively easy adding the local.properties file. The necessary content is just

`sdk.dir=/path/to/android/sdk`

This solves the problem and IntelliJ is now able to import the project. No further info on using environment variables.

Answer (score 3):

This is unorthodox but I cannot comment(not enough karma) so I'm writing an answer instead, where is the `local.properties` file that you speak of? I am unable to find it.

However I've solved it by:

- open your `Project Structure` settings (Ctrl+alt+shift+s)
- Under the `Platform Settings` group select `SDKs`
- with the `+` sign add `Android SDK` > Select your /path/to/android/sdk
- Select build target

  - *Optional* : I've also named the sdk as 'android' I am unsure whether this fixed anything but it does make sdk's ambiguous
- Apply
- Go to `Project Settings` and choose `Modules`
- Select `android` and under `Module Sdk` choose the android sdk we just added (renaming can come in handy here).
- Apply, wait and done.

Comment: The local.properties file can be created at the project root if it's not there. But your method should work as well :)

Comment: @kiliankoe looking back at this, it seems that the local.properties file is generated as well. Yours is probably more hassle-free.

Answer (score 2):

On IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2 it's worked this way for me:

- Menu `File` -> `Other Settings` -> `Default Project Structure...`
- There on the left under `Project Settings` -> `Projects`
- Click on `New...` button
- Choose `Android SDK` and insert path to it.

After that for you new or imported projects IDEA will know where to find Android SDK

Comment: Brilliant! I was unable to edit the SDK path in Preferences > Android SDK > Android SDK Location. But this worked for me in IntelliJ 2017.3!